# GKLocalPlayer authentication not working, but isAuthenticated returns YES (Game Center sandbox)

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I'm working on integrating turn based matches in my game and a few days ago I started getting weird errors from the GameKit API saying that the local player is not authenticated, even though he is.

When I launch the app, the `authenticateHandler` is called, the view controller is displayed and after entering the password, the `authenticaHandler` is called again and the local player seems to be authenticated. `isAuthenticated` returns `YES`.

But as soon as I start using any of the GameKit APIs like `loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:`, an error is returned saying that the player has not been authenticated.

This is the code for handling authentication changes.

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
    if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]) {
        // Player authenticated
    } else {
        // Player not authenticated

        if (viewController != nil) {
            // Present view controller
        }
    }
}];
```

And this is the error message I receive when calling any of the GameKit methods. Please note that `-isAuthenticated` still returns YES when the error is returned.

> Error finding match: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=6 "The requested operation could not be completed because local player has not been authenticated." UserInfo=0x14e9f950 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because local player has not been authenticated.}
>   (lldb) print (BOOL) [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]
>   (BOOL) $3 = YES

I'm testing in the Game Center sandbox and it started happening a few days ago. Previously, I didn't experience the problem at all.
It only happens about one of three times when the app is started. I have tried deleting the app, restarting my devices, cleaning the build folder and everything else I could think of.

Am I missing something or has anybody else experienced similar problems?

Comment: Did you figure out how to resolve this error? My game is getting this pop-up error.

Answer (score 2):

This rich [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) is a great place to look at. Here are 2 things which I would suggest -

1. Game Center fails to complete authentication if your device has
   incorrect dates. So,   go ahead and check the current date.
2. You might have done this. I trust you - iOS Simulator >> Reset
   Content and Settings

Do you think there could be something wrong with the way you are using `-[GKLocalPlayer loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:]`? Nothing wrong with your authentication function above, but I'd love to share mine if it works for you -

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer{

    // Instantiate a GKLocalPlayer object to use for authenticating a player.
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {

            // If it's needed display the login view controller.
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
        else {
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                // If the player is already authenticated then indicate that the Game Center features can be used.

                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;

            }

            else {
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It's not just loading friends but also ending turns or reporting achievements. This doesn't happen that often anymore so I think it might just have been a temporary problem with the Game Center sandbox servers. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using Game Kit Framework?
From iOS 7 you should use MultipeerConnectivity.

1) – authenticateWithCompletionHandler: Deprecated in iOS 6.0.
And if you test on iOS 7 it may be doesn't work at all.

2) Below example for create connection via MultipeerConnectivity

Client:

```
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *peerName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", @"Client", [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString];
        self.myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:peerName];

        self.servers = [NSMutableArray array];

        self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID securityIdentity:nil encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
        self.session.delegate = self;
        self.browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID serviceType:@"Connect"];
        self.browser.delegate = self;
        [self.browser startBrowsingForPeers];
  }
  return self;
}
//-----
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        NSLog(@"client: found a server: %@", peerID);
        [self.browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:self.session withContext:nil timeout:10];

}

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser lostPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
        NSLog(@"client: lost server: %@", peerID);
}

#pragma mark - MCSessionDelegate
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state {
        NSLog(@"client: status changed to %d for server: %@", state, peerID.displayName);

        switch (state) {
         case MCSessionStateNotConnected: {

        }
             break;
         case MCSessionStateConnected: {

        }
             break;
         default:
             break;
        }
  }

   - (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
        NSLog(@"client: received data (len = %lu) from server %@",(unsigned long)[data length], peerID.displayName);
        NSDictionary *receiveDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    }
```

Server:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            NSString *peerName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", @"Server", [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString];
            self.myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:peerName];

            self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID];
            self.session.delegate = self;

            self.advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID
                                                                discoveryInfo:nil
                                                                  serviceType:@"Connect"];
            self.advertiser.delegate = self;
           [self.advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
         }
     return self;
}

#pragma mark - MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate

- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session))invitationHandler {
     NSLog(@"server: did receive invitation from peer %@", peerID.displayName);
     invitationHandler(YES, self.session);
 }

- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didNotStartAdvertisingPeer:(NSError *)error {
      NSLog(@"server: error %@", error);
 }

 #pragma mark - MCSessionDelegate

 - (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state {
      NSLog(@"server: status changed to %ld for client: %@", state, peerID.displayName);

      switch (state) {
       case MCSessionStateConnected: {   
           NSMutableDictionary *sendDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
           NSError *error = nil;
           [self.session sendData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sendDict]
                           toPeers:@[peerID]
                          withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable
                             error:&error];
         }
           break;
        case MCSessionStateNotConnected:
         break;
        default:
         break;
       }
       NSLog(@"connectedPeers %@", self.session.connectedPeers);
   }

   - (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
       NSLog(@"server: received data (len = %lu) from client %@", (unsigned long)[data length], peerID.displayName);

       NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    }

    - (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveStream:(NSInputStream *)stream withName:(NSString *)streamName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
    }

    - (void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress {
    }

    - (void)session:(MCSession *)session didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID atURL:(NSURL *)localURL withError:(NSError *)error {
    }

    - (void)session:(MCSession*)session didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray*)certificate fromPeer:(MCPeerID*)peerID certificateHandler:(void (^)(BOOL accept))certificateHandler {
          certificateHandler(YES);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using GameKit for achievements and leaderboards, using MultipeerConnectivity is not an option.

Comment: Make sure "A new player may have logged into the device or the player may have simply logged out from Game Center." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLocalPlayer/authenticated

Comment: I'm testing this on my device, I'm the only user. Sorry, but I don't think you understand my problem here.

Comment: The gentleman above cracked me up with MultipeerConnectivity code for this question!